# Can't modify FormatString on cube ( SSAS )

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssas

I'm trying to create a cube, to know a little more about SSAS and as a DBA, be prepared for anything ( almost ).

When I'm changing SalesAmmount's `FormatString` to `Currency`, it doesn't change the values to currency. It keeps the big number values.

[image]

[image]

What am I missing? I tried to find some "currency language" or another option with no success.

( The Canada is a little motivation with my objective to move to Canada :) )

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is that the new cube browser control in Data Tools doesn't support format strings.

OLAP clients are free to respect those formats or not, so some clients just don't respect the format string.

Testing in Excel should however display the formatted values correctly.